# Line breaking issue "C"

Tags: c, struct, line-breaks

I have a noticed a strange bug in my short code. The purpose of this script is to create an array of structures that contain some information about cars

```
("Struct Car Car1: char brand[50], char model[50], int ccm, int hp, int kw, char[50]")
```

After running the script everything is fine up until the first instance is filled, but when the variable `i` has been incremented by 1, the line break disappears from between the lines where I ask the user to provide the "BRAND" and the "MODEL". I am sorry for being a noob this is my first time using structs. Thanks for any kind of help.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<time.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #define MAX 10
    
    int main() {
    
        struct Car {
            char brand[50];     
            char model[50];     
            int ccm;            
            int hp;             
            int kw;             
            char wheel[50];     
        };
    
        struct Car Car1;
        strcpy(Car1.brand, "Skoda");
        strcpy(Car1.model, "Octavia");
        Car1.ccm = 1960;
        Car1.hp = 170;
        Car1.kw = 114;
        strcpy(Car1.wheel, "215/75R18");
    
        printf("The car's brand is: %s\n", Car1.brand);
        printf("The model is: %s\n", Car1.model);
        printf("The volume of the engine is %d ccm\n", Car1.ccm);
        printf("It has %d horsepower\n", Car1.hp);
        printf("The car has %d kws\n", Car1.kw);
        printf("You can put: %s wheels on it\n", Car1.wheel);
    
        struct Car car_arr[MAX];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            printf("Enter details of a car: %d\n", i+1);
            printf("\n");
            printf("Enter the brand: ");
            fgets(car_arr[i].brand, sizeof car_arr[i].brand, stdin); //Brand
            car_arr[i].brand[strcspn(car_arr[i].brand, "\n")] = '\0';
            printf("Enter the model: ");
            fgets(car_arr[i].model, sizeof car_arr[i].model, stdin); //Model
            car_arr[i].model[strcspn(car_arr[i].model, "\n")] = '\0';
            printf("Enter the parameters of the wheel: ");
            fgets(car_arr[i].wheel, sizeof car_arr[i].wheel, stdin); //Wheel
            car_arr[i].wheel[strcspn(car_arr[i].wheel, "\n")] = '\0';
            printf("Enter the volume of the engine in ccms: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &car_arr[i].ccm);
            printf("Enter the horsepower: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &car_arr[i].hp);
            printf("Enter the amount of kilowatts: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &car_arr[i].kw);
            
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with structs per se, but you mix line-wise scanning with `fgets` with white-space separated scanning with `scanf`. C is not really good with interactive input, but the general recommendation is to read lines of input first, then scan that line for input, for example with `sscanf`.

Comment: Classic problem of mixing fgets and scanf.  scanf only reads up to what you ask for.  fgets reads the whole line including the trailing newline.  So if you call fgets after scanf, you just get the newline left by scanf.

Comment: (Unrelated, but I think your user shouldn't have to input the power in both HP and kW. They're both the same quantity and by asking the user both, they might enter incongrous values. Ask foe one and convert on output, eg "114 kW (170 HP)".)

Comment: I have been trying to use the scanf version but I could not figure out how to store the scanned string in my structure. The VS always pops up an exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tha above comments answered your question, but as a side note:
You can save yourself some repetition by using "typedef" together with "struct".

typedef struct { int x1; long x2; double etc; } my_type;